# OpenRouteService: getting "float not iterable" when requesting isochrones via API

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I'm trying to request isochrones via the [openrouteservice API](https://openrouteservice.org/documentation/#reference/isochrones/isochrones-service). This requires that I pass to the API, as a parameter, a dict containing various options, including the lng-lat values to be used as the isochrones' origin points.

I'm working off their example at [this link](https://openrouteservice.org/example-apartment-search-with-ors/) (look for "Apartment Isochrones"). When I try to pass coordinates to the API, I'm getting a TypeError (float not iterable), and I can't tell what I'm doing differently from the sample code to cause the error.

I've copied their code below:

```
api_key = '' #Provide your personal API key
clnt = client.Client(key=api_key) 
# Set up folium map
map1 = folium.Map(tiles='Stamen Toner', location=([37.738684, -122.450523]), zoom_start=12)

# Set up the apartment dictionary with real coordinates
apt_dict = {'first': {'location': [-122.430954, 37.792965]},
            'second': {'location': [-122.501636, 37.748653]},
            'third': {'location': [-122.446629, 37.736928]}
           }

# Request of isochrones with 15 minute footwalk.
params_iso = {'profile': 'foot-walking',
              'intervals': [900], # 900/60 = 15 mins
              'segments': 900,
              'attributes': ['total_pop'] # Get population count for isochrones
             }

for name, apt in apt_dict.items():
    params_iso['locations'] = apt['location'] # Add apartment coords to request parameters
    apt['iso'] = clnt.isochrones(**params_iso) # Perform isochrone request
    folium.features.GeoJson(apt['iso']).add_to(map1) # Add GeoJson to map

    # reverse coords due to weird folium lat/lon syntax
    folium.map.Marker(list(reversed(apt['location'])), 
                  icon=folium.Icon(color='lightgray',
                                    icon_color='#cc0000',
                                    icon='home',
                                    prefix='fa',
                                   ),
                                   popup=name,
                      ).add_to(map1) # Add apartment locations to map
```

And mine, for comparison:

```
# import modules
import geopandas as gpd
from openrouteservice import client

# from local directory, read in file containing coordinates to be used
data = gpd.read_file("layers/Bridgeport_stores.geojson")
read_source = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data)

# set API key and configure client
api_key = 'my_key'
clnt = client.Client(key=api_key)

# create array for storing coordinate pairs as lists
# I didn't do it this way originally, but changed it while error-checking - it seems to behave exactly like I want
coordinate_array = []
for i in range(len(read_source)):
    coordinate_array.append([read_source.geometry.x[i], read_source.geometry.y[i]])
# print for verification
print(coordinate_array)

# create dict for storing coordinates
# loop through array, storing coordinates as API will expect them
for i in range(len(read_source)):
    lng = read_source.geometry.x[i]
    lat = round(read_source.geometry.y[i]
coordinate_dict.update({i: {"location": coordinate_array[i]}})

# create dict with parameters to pass to API (as seen in example)
isochrone_parameters = {"profile": "foot-walking",
                    "intervals": [900],
                    "segments": 900,
                    "attributes": ["total_pop"]
                    }

# request isochrones from openrouteservice, and store in dict
# (storing in dict for error-checking purposes - in example, they plot each isochrone on the map)
isochrone_dict = {}
for row, location in coordinate_dict.items():
    isochrone_parameters["locations"] = location["location"]
    isochrone_dict.update({location: clnt.isochrones(**isochrone_parameters)})
print(isochrone_dict)
```

The error message points me to the line where the API request takes place (i.e. `isochrone_dict.update({location: clnt.isochrones(**isochrone_parameters)})`).

While error-checking, I tried to see what would happen if one set of coordinates were hard-coded, as a list, into the parameters. This, when passed to the API, works - it produces one isochrone. It's only when I try to use a loop to access multiple values within the dict that it throws the error.

I understand the idea of the error, but I'm kind of at a loss, because as far as I can tell I'm handling the dict basically how the example code (which works) does.

For reference, [here](http://openrouteservice-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-openrouteservice.isochrones) is a link to some lengthier documentation.